# What to multiply by to get correct form ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $y'' + f(x)y = 0$ where $M \geq f(x) \geq m > 0$ on some interval $[a,b]$, then the number zeros $N$ of a non trivial solution is $\lfloor\frac{(b-a)\sqrt{m}}{\pi}\rfloor \leq N \leq \lceil\frac{(b-a)\sqrt{M}}{\pi}\rceil$

Simple.

Now suppose I have an equation $y''+4y'+\frac{8x+\sin(x)}{x+1}y = 0$ and I want to estimate the number of zeros of a non trivial solution.

I can't use the theorem as is, because the ODE is not in the correct form, to fix this, we can multiply by $e^{2x}$ and get $y''e^{2x}+4y'e^{2x}+\frac{8x+\sin(x)}{x+1}ye^{2x} = 0$

Now if we let $ye^{2x} = z$ we have an ODE $z'' + (\frac{8x+\sin(x)}{x+1}-4)z = 0$ which is in the correct form

**How did the professor know to multiply by** $e^{2x}$? Is there a method to this or was this just a lucky guess

Answer (score 1):

If $y=ze^{g(x)}$ then we can calculate that $y'=e^{g}(z'+zg')$ and $y''=e^{g}(z''+2z'g'+zg''+z(g')^2)$.

An equation of the form $y''+A(x)y'+B(x)=0$ can then be written in terms of $z$ as $e^{g}\left(z''+(2g'+A(x))z'+(g''+A(x)g'+(g')^2+B(x))\right)=0$.

For this to be in the form $z''+f(x)z=0$ we need to have $2g'+A(x)=0$. So the desired substitution is $y=ze^{\int A(x)/2 \mathrm{d}x}$.

Answer (score 1):

For me is the idea in this:

Ignore the ugly part of the equation.
What we need is to shift $y''+4y'$ so that we get $z''$. Since this first part corresponds to a linear ODE with a quadratic characteristic equation, the trick leads me to the perfect square of $r^2+4r$ which is $(r+2)^2-4.$ This says that $r=-2$ makes the job. A corresponding solution would be $e^{-2x}.$ Multiplying the initial equation by the inverse of $e^{-2x}$ makes what expected.